# What is the Apache Spark equivalent of excel's solver or R's optim function?

Tags: apache-spark

I can find the approximate minimum for a complex non-linear function in excel using the solver.

I can do the same in R using the optim function.

I have my function coded and working in apache spark.

I have searched the [apache spark machine learning documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html) and found models for regression and classification, but not any tools like R's optim or Excel's solver. Did I miss something?

What is the apache spark equivalent to R's optim function or excel's solver?

Comment: spark is a batch-processing framework. The standard library is meant for processing data encoded in resilient-distributed-dataframes. It is originally not designed for tackling such problems.

Comment: Benoit - thx  I updated my question based on your comment. Newer versions of spark have replaced RDD's with dataframes and added machine learning capabilities. I just couldn't find any solvers in the Spark documentation, and hoped someone could show me where it is if I missed it.

Comment: spark mlib has a couple of optimizers, such as gradient descent.? do you mean these? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/mllib-optimization.html

The formula of the gradients is already fixed for a set of loss functions. It is not as flexible as tensorflow or pytorch. These are better frameworks for this type of problems.

Comment: That might be it,  I am reading that part of the Spark documentation now.

Comment: Benoit, the link you provided (spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/mllib-optimization.html) is precisely the answer I was looking for. I didn't know the vocabulary to recognize it as such without a tip. If you please add that as an answer I'll mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spark mlib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/mllib-optimization.html) has a couple of optimizers, such as gradient descent.